# Is it possible to access row id of a google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I get an array of rows/columns within a RANGE using "GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets//values/".
It has no information on row Id though.

Is it possible to retrieve a row id ? It'll be helpful to update/delete the specific row even if the row number changes .

Comment: @Nikhil....share your answer here...it will helpfull to all...same thing i need

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this unfortunately — which is a bit of a shocker, to be honest.  I'm not sure why Google would decide **not** to have this feature implemented in their API.  A user *could* add a column to the spreadsheet in question and make the values unique, but that is exactly the point of the index column inherent to the spreadsheet.

Therefore, my answer is that you just ad a column with a header named "unique-id" and then each cell under that column uses the formula `=ROW()` which will return the value of that row.  Then, you can access the value of that column via the Google Sheets API — either list-based feed or cell-based feed.  However, if you use the list-based feel, and modify the row, the formula gets altered to just the calculated value.  So, it's really a moot point to do it this way if you intend to modify rows using the list-based (rows-based) feed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a row id in the v4 API.

Comment: With respect to the downvote, I'm not sure what other answer you would prefer.  You can add a column with your own unique IDs and search for that. The simple fact of the matter is the question as asked is not possible.

Comment: @Pls provide details here...how to perform that operation

Answer (score 1):

If I'm referencing the correct `Google Sheets API`, which has confused me at times, you can use `getRow()` or `getRowIndex()`, no?

[getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow)
[getRowIndex()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrowindex)

Comment: ...possible to give answer here in objective-c

Comment: This answer is about using Google Apps Script, not the Google Sheets API which is what the original question is asking.  Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

=row()
Returns the row number of a specified cell.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en

best regards